# Latex signature field on document

Tags: pspicture, signatures

I am new to latex and I want to write a document.

My document code looks like this (I am editing out big textblocks):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{5mm}{0.6mm}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\centering}


\begin{document}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 
    \fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont
\begin{textblock}{120}(1, 1)
    \textbf{Anlage /}
\end{textblock}
\vspace*{-2.7cm}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}{}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
            \hline
            \textbf{Mieter: 
            \begin{textblock}{40}(19, 8)
                hallo
            \end{textblock}} \\
            \hline
            \textbf{Straße:
            \begin{textblock}{40}(19, 12)
                hallo   
            \end{textblock}} \\
            \hline
            \textbf{PLZ/Ort:
            \begin{textblock}{40}(19, 15)
                hallo   
            \end{textblock}} \\
            \hline
            \textbf{Tel:/Fax:
            \begin{textblock}{40}(21, 18)
                hallo   
            \end{textblock}} \\
            \hline
            \textbf{E-Mail:
            \begin{textblock}{40}(19, 21)
                hallo   
            \end{textblock}} \\
            \hline
            \textbf{Mietobjekt:
            \begin{textblock}{40}(24, 24.5)
                hallo   
            \end{textblock}} \\
            \textbf{Produkttyp
            \begin{textblock}{40}(5, 31)
                hallo   
            \end{textblock}} \\ \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
            \hline
            \textbf{Servicepartner:} \\
            \hline
            \textbf{Straße:}  \\
            \hline
            \textbf{PLZ/Ort:}  \\
            \hline
            \textbf{Tel:/Fax:}  \\
            \hline
            \textbf{E-Mail:} \\
            \hline
            \textbf{Abweichender Standort:} \\ \\ \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{adjustwidth}
\section{Service}
\begin{textblock}{195}(1, 50)
    Secret Text
\subsection{Services:}
    \begin{itemize}
        \setlength\itemsep{-0.4em}
        \item secret
        \item secret
        \item secret
    \end{itemize}
Big block of text
\section{Service2}
More text
\end{textblock}
\end{document}
```

At the end I want to have a signature field looking like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTeJv.png)

How can I do that?

[image: zz]

Comment: You can include images in your question, no need for an external link. Don't use the ngerman package, use \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} instead. And are you sure that you want to use pstricks, texpos, sectsty (which probably clash with your class) and changepage (which imho is unneeded in your class)?

Comment: then move everything from your preamble with the exception of the class and babel to some other file and move then back only if you know that you really need them (and after you have read the first pages of their documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution for the signature box.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 

\usepackage[left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm]{geometry} % set margins

% **************** needed
\newsavebox{\xtext}
\savebox{\xtext}{%
\sffamily\footnotesize\ ,den\ } 
\usepackage{array} % added <<<<<<<<<
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
% ****************


\begin{document}
    
    
%% *******************************************************  signature box
\setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}  
\fbox{\sffamily\footnotesize%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
\begin{tabular}{L{0.4\linewidth}L{0.15\linewidth}L{0.4\linewidth}}
    \textbf{Der Mieter (MI)} & &\textbf{Der service Partner} \\[7ex]
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \rule{0.5\linewidth}{1pt}\usebox{\xtext}&\rule{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-\wd\xtext}{1pt}\\
        Ort  &  Datum \\
    \end{tabular} &&
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \rule{0.5\linewidth}{1pt}\usebox{\xtext}&\rule{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-\wd\xtext}{1pt}\\
        Ort  &  Datum \\
    \end{tabular}\\[8ex]        
    \rule{\linewidth}{1pt} &&\rule{\linewidth}{1pt} \\
    (MI) rechtsgültige Unterschift/Firmenstempel&&  (Lieferant) rechtsgültige Unterschift/Firmenstempel \\[7ex]
    \rule{\linewidth}{1pt} && \\
    (MI) Vor - und Zumane in Druckbuchstaben &&
                
\end{tabular}}

% *******************************************************   end signature box

\end{document}
```

It is based on a tabular, three columns with fixed width (the middle one remains empty). This structure makes it easy to align the left and right lines.

The box will automatically adjust to different margins or text widths.

The space between horizontal lines can be changed by using `[<space>]` after `\\`

The width of the interior rules was chosen as 1pt (`\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}`) and the exterior frame has a width of 2pt (`\setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}` ).